Confused between Universal C Runtime and Visual C++ Redistributable
I am trying to figure out the pre-requisites a user will need to install on their machine before installing my application. My application has following dependencies:

and I developed it on Windows 11 using latest SDK as of this writing.
On my development computer it runs fine but obviously that has all the dev libraries installed which would be missing on a client's computer. I have come across these two links:

Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable
Universal C Runtime

and I'd like to know if any of these are needed as pre-requisites and if they don't already come pre-installed on Windows. Based on my readings my gathering is that:

yes both will be needed and
the Universal C Runtime is pre-installed on Windows 10 or later (so no action required to install this on Windows 10 or later).

Is that correct? Also any guidance on how I can develop WiX installer that will correctly install these pre-requisites on user's machine? I don't know much C++ so sorry if asking a noob question.

There's a lot to be said for linking against the static versions of the runtime library (/MT).  That avoids all this misery.

Just vcruntime and msvcp.  The ucrt is available on any machine that is being maintained by Windows Update, that's what makes it universal.  Expecting to install on a machine that is not maintained is a bad idea.

You need the VC++ runtime. You can install it as part of your installer. If it's already installed, then skip it. Note that you need to distribute the same (or later) version of VC++ that you compiled against. OR you can statically link against the vcrt.

When you deploy a Visual C++ application to another computer, you must install both the application and any library files it depends on. Visual Studio enables three ways to deploy the Visual C++ libraries together with your application: central deployment, local deployment, and static linking.

(From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deployment-in-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170)

UCRT is not required for you to install, as it's part of Windows Update

The Universal CRT (UCRT) is a Microsoft Windows operating system component. It's included as part of the operating system in Windows 10 or later, and Windows Server 2016 or later. The UCRT is available by using Windows Update on older operating systems that are still in extended support.

(From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/universal-crt-deployment?view=msvc-170)
